# JQuery select class name that consists of 2 specific words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

is there a way to select class name based on 2 words

for example  these 5  classes

```
<div class="catsanddogs">1</div>
 <div class="cats and dogs">2</div>
 <div class="anddogs">3</div>
 <div class="catand">4</div>
 <div class="catsanddogs">5</div>
```

I want to select the class that consists of  these 2 words  cats, dogs

And only the first one will be effected

```
 <div class="catsanddogs">1</div>
 <div class="cats and dogs">2</div>
 <div class="catsanddogs">5</div>
```

then apply the changes on first one only because the three of them has the words
so it will select these 3

is that possible  using jquery ??

I found a way to select class that start with certain word   but I want anywhere in the class name

```
$('[class="catsanddogs"]').html('test');
```

but its only match the first one!

I know jquery has (:first ) but the problem with finding what matches these 2 names

Comment: Do you mean literally any combination of a value that contains 'cats' and 'dogs'?

Comment: @Taplar class name that contain these words   it might be joined or separated names  joined like this "catsanddogs"  and separated like this  "cats and dogs"

Comment: What about "dogs and cats"?

Comment: notice that the class name has dogs, cats => "catsanddogs"   I want a way to select classes that has 2 words I specify. cats and dogs is just example

Comment: I'm asking if the order is important.  Do you also want to select those that have dogs before cats, or only cats before dogs

Comment: No the order is not important  anyway I got the answer I want.  Thank you for trying I really appreciate that

Comment: It's cool.  Both of the solutions below provide the same selector, :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to select the class that consists of these 2 words cats, dogs

You can use the [**contains**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `*=` selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[class*=cats][class*=dogs]').addClass('match');
});
```

```css
.match{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catsanddogs">catsanddogs</div>
<div class="cats and dogs">cats and dogs</div>
<div class="anddogs">anddogs</div>
<div class="catand">catand</div>
<div class="catsanddogs">catsanddogs</div>
```

Comment: Ohh nice one  I just added :first  to work like I want   like this "[class*=cats][class*=dogs]:first"     it looks easy when you get the answer.   Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just like css selectors, you can select an element that has two classes with:

```
$('.class1.class2')
```

Or if you truly want any combination of the two.

```js
console.log($('[class*="cats"][class*="dogs"]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catsanddogs">1</div>
<div class="cats and dogs">2</div>
<div class="anddogs">3</div>
<div class="catand">4</div>
<div class="catsanddogs">5</div>
```